# Algorithm that finds the minimum number of containers required to cover a list of items

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a problem not specific to any language or framework, it's more like an algorithm question:

I have a list of "containers" that contain various items. Each item contained in a container has a quantity and a type, so maybe one container has 3 apples and 2 peaches, another container has 12 peaches and yet another has 5 pears.

I have to come up with an algorithm that takes in this information plus a request, and returns the minimum number of containers that can satifsy such request. The request is essentially a list of wanted items together with their wanted quantity, think of it like a shopping list.

So based on the example I gave above:

```
Container A:
    3 x apple
    2 x peach

Container B:
    12 x peach

Container C:
    5 x pear
```

and this request

```
I want:
    1 x apple
    6 x peach
```

the algorithm should tell me that the best way to satifsy this request is using both container A and B and that 1 apple and 2 peaches will be consumed from A and 4 peaches will be consumed from B (Or maybe all 6 peaches are consumed from B and A is used only for the apple, it really doesn't matter).

Also the algorithm should be able to tell when a request can't be satisfied based on available containers (for instance: a request of 35 watermelons wouldn't be possible to satisfy) and also give different priorities to different containers when possible (for instance: containers that are quicker to deliver should receive a boost compared to other containers with very similar contents but much harder to deliver quickly to the customer).

So far I've tried using a very trivial and kinda crappy scoring algorithm (pseudocode):

```
itemsLeft = copy(itemsInRequest)
containersLeft = copy(containers)
choosenContainers = []

while len(itemsLeft) > 0:
    if len(containersLeft) == 0:
        return Error("No more containers, can't satisfy request")
    bestScore = 0
    bestContainer = null
    foreach container in containersLeft:
        // Give a score based on the items it contains
        score = 0
        foreach item in itemsLeft:
            if container.contains(item.type):
                score += min(container.quantityOf(item.type), item.wantedQty)
        // Take priority into account
        score += container.priority
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestContainer = container
    choosenContainers.append(bestContainer)
    containersLeft.remove(bestContainer)
    foreach item in itemsLeft:
        if bestContainer.contains(item.type):
            quantityInContainer = bestContainer.quantityOf(item.type)
            // This will consume items in itemsLeft, eventually
            // removing them from the list if the quantity
            // reaches 0
            item.consume(quantityInContainer)
return choosenContainers
```

But I'm not very satisfied with it because I don't think it's well thought out and performant but I can't come up with anything better at the moment.

Also I don't think it handle edge cases very well. For instance: imagine a request cannot be satisfied with available containers. This algorithm will pick all containers without really achieving anything, just because the priority will give them a little non-zero score.

I was thinking that maybe something like this can be achieved with some already existing, battle proven algorithm that I'm not aware of?

Can you recommend any algorithm that solves this class of problems or a similar one so I can take inspiration from it or maybe give some suggestions about how you would tackle this problem?

Comment: This is an NP hard problem, and you can use an integer linear program solver like GLPK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your solution has another problem than being badly optimized/badly handling impossibles cases.

For example, with this test case:

```
Container A:
    10 apples
Container B:
    5 apples
    1 pear
Container C:
    5 apples
    1 pear
Request:
    10 apples
    2 pears
```

Your code will returns 3 containers (container A giving the best score at iteration 1).

There is a simple approach giving correct result but having an exponential complexity:

```
resultContainers = None
resultNumberContainers = inf
for each binary_mask in range(0, pow(2,containerLength)):
    actContainer = emptyContainer
    numberContainers = 0
    for each i in range(0,containerLength):
        if(pow(2,i) & binary_mask):
            actContainer = actContainer + containers[i]
            numberContainers += 1
    if(ok(actContainer) && numberContainers < resultNumberContainers):
        resultNumberContainers = numberContainers
        resultContainers = actContainer
```

Comment: Does the code you provided come from a known algorithm for solving this class of problems or is it something you came up with? I'm asking because I would like to research this more in depth and I'm not really understanding the snippet

Comment: It is some kind of known techniques, known as "binary mask".  

The principle is the following one:  

binary_mask is a number, whose binary representation is exploited to solve a problem.  

For example here, binary mask "101" means we take the first and third container and not the second (bit 1 and 3 are equal to 1, bit 2 is equal to 0)  

So I try every binary mask (every combination of containers) (000, 001, 010 ... 110, 111) and count the number of bits equal to 1 to get the number of container used.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved by looking at each container and deciding on whether to include (take) container *i*.

So we traverse through all containers one after another and for each container we look branch out with 2 choices: 
 1. **INCLUDE** Container
 2. **EXCLUDE** Container

We do this call recursively. At each call if we are including the container we need to increment #of Containers. At the same time decrement #of remaining items.

We keep doing this until we reach a situation where no containers are left, or we have satisfied all the items required.
We then take the *min* of all the values seen.